# Authorization form un unity with firebase

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I need a create people authorization in Unity, i find Firebase code, but she said:

> Assets\AuthFormLoginExist.cs(16,9): error CS0103: The name 'auth' does
> not exist in the current context
> Assets\AuthFormLoginExist.cs(16,46): error CS0103: The name 'email' does not exist in the current context
> Assets\AuthFormLoginExist.cs(16,53): error CS0103: The name 'password' does not exist in the current context

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AuthChecker : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);
                return;
            }

            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
        });
    }
}
```

And I can't find answer in Google.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to add an auth variable.
Like so:

```
public class AuthChecker : MonoBehaviour
{
protected static Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth;

void Start()
{
    auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
}


void FunctionWhichStartTheAuthentication()
{
    auth.SignInWithEmailAndPas//..... (the rest of your code is ok)
```

But dont do that in update. (update gets called every frame)

Comment: Thank You for help, but problem also continues ||| error CS0103: The name 'email' does not exist in the current context Assets\AuthFormLoginExist.cs ||| (16,53): error CS0103: The name 'password' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: The email and password parameters you are sending to the SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync method are variables. you should change them to the email and password you want to send (eg inputField value). if, for example you will change the (email, password) part to ("test@test.test","123456") it will work ok